# File Picker Filter Not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, filepicker

I must be missing something...

This is my code:

```
   OpenFileDialog o = new OpenFileDialog();
   o.Filter = "SQL Server Compact Edition Database File|.sdf";
   o.ShowDialog();
```

In the actual folder there is definitely a .sdf file:

[image]

And then in the file picker (the same folder) it doesn't show it:

[image]

Is it because it only works for certain types of files or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're just missing the `*` wildcard in the matching part:

```
o.Filter = "SQL Server Compact Edition Database File|*.sdf";
```